# "Slipped into the hole" vs "x slipped and fell into the hole"

Tags: prepositions

As you know, some prepositions such as **into, onto and unto** may be used with movement verbs, which is the case of: I knocked something into, I dropped something into, I put something into...

Anyway, can these prepositions be used with verbs such as *slip* and *slide?*

*I slipped into the hole* - It would mean that I slipped on something and fell into a hole as I slipped.

*I slid into a hole* - It would mean I slid on probably a wet floor and fell into a hole. (Basically the same as above)

I know it could possibly sound like I slid/slipped in the hole (which doesn't make sense) because people normally use: I slipped/slid on a wet floor/the ground/ the floor... However, since I added **in/on + to** it becomes a movement, which implies to say I'm going towards that direction: **Into the hole** = **Inside the hole**.

I have two questions: *Could it possibly be right (grammatically) even if it sounded awkward to say something like: I slipped/slid into the hole?*

And: Even if saying the above suggestion is correct, saying: **I slipped/slid and fell into the hole** would sound better?

Comment: This question is better asked on our sister site, [ELL.se]; I've kicked off the process to migrate it there. FYI, "I slipped into the hole" does not necessarily imply you fell. You can skip into something intentionally, without falling.

Answer (score 2):

I slipped into the hole - It would mean that I slipped on something and fell into a hole as I slipped.

It could also mean you did it intentionally.

> I slipped/slid between the sheets.
>
> I slipped into the alley so my pursuer would not find me.
>
> I slid into first before the baseman could touch me.

If it was **unintentional**, then you must make that clear/qualify it.

> I slipped and fell into the hole.

Answer (score 0):

It is grammatically correct to say

> I slipped/slid into the hole

And is in fact more natural.

Although, when describing an event, it depends which came first.

> I slipped and fell into the hole

Means that you slipped first (probably on something, like a banana skin) and then fell into the hole as a result of the slip

> I fell and slid into the hole

Means that you fell first (probably over something, like a low railing) and then slipped down a hill as a result of the fall, conveniently, right into a hole.

To be clear, slid and slipped are interchangeable, although in certain contexts, one might make more sense over the other, although both should be understood in the vast majority of contexts.